# Detect duplicate email id in arraylist containg multiple employee objects

Tags: java, collections

Suppose I have a arraylist , I am dynamically adding multiple employee objects to the arraylist. Employee object have field like Id, name, email . My requirement is when I am adding a employee object to arraylist. Suppose that object having a email which is already there of another object added to arraylist. Then it should not allow to add current object to the arraylist or show some error message.Is there any methods available in Collection module to achieve this thing in shortest possible way..

Comment: `ArrayList` is not optimal storage collection. I think  you could use `Map` instead

Comment: I suggest that you start by turning off our computer and get a piece of paper and a pencil. Now write **in words** the steps needed to solve your problem. Do not worry at all about the Java syntax. Just concentrate on how you would solve the problem if you had to do it by hand.

Comment: I have the answer for this question. But I need a shortest possible way to achieve this target using  a any predefined collection class methods or something.that's why I asked here..

Comment: Could you share what kind of solution you already have? It could help us understand what you already have and if that could be improved at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Use LinkedHashMap to keep insertion order
Map<String, Employee> employees = new LinkedHashMap<>();

// v1: add new employee with unique email
employees.putIfAbsent(employee.getEmail(), employee);

// v2: add new employee and show message for duplication email
if(employees.containsKey(employee.getEmail()))
    System.out.println("Email " + employee.getEmail() + " duplication");
else
    employees.put(employee.getEmail(), employee);

// get all employees in order they were added
List<Employee> res = new ArrayList<>(employees.values());
```

Comment: 1 this is what I am looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

if i got your question correctly u need to avoid duplicates for employee object based on emailaddress attribute. I would recommend to use Sets instead of arraylist.

this is how you would do with sets with overriding equals and hashcode.

```
 package com.test.testing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );

        Employee employee = new Employee("anilhk@gmail.com", "1");
        Employee employee2 = new Employee("abc@gmail.com", "2");
        Employee employee3 = new Employee("anilhk@gmail.com", "3");

        List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        empList.add(employee);
        empList.add(employee2);
        empList.add(employee3);

        System.out.println("Employee List " +empList);

        Set<Employee> empSet = new HashSet<Employee>();

        for (Employee emp : empList) {

            if (empSet.contains(emp)) {
                System.out.println("Employee with employee email " +emp.getEmailAddress() + " and employee id " +emp.getId() +" already exists");
            } 
            else {
                empSet.add(emp);
            }

        }

        System.out.println(empSet);
    }

    private static class Employee {

        private String emailAddress;
        private String id;


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Employee [emailAddress=" + emailAddress + ", id=" + id + "]";
        }

        public Employee(String emailAddress, String id) {
            this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
            this.id = id;
        }

            public String getEmailAddress() {
            return emailAddress;
        }

        public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
            this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((emailAddress == null) ? 0 : emailAddress.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!(obj instanceof Employee)) {
                return false;
            }
            Employee other = (Employee) obj;
            if (emailAddress == null) {
                if (other.emailAddress != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!emailAddress.equals(other.emailAddress)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }





    }

}
```

output.

```
  Hello World!
Employee List [Employee [emailAddress=anilhk@gmail.com, id=1], Employee [emailAddress=abc@gmail.com, id=2], Employee [emailAddress=anilhk@gmail.com, id=3]]
Employee with employee email anilhk@gmail.com and employee id 3 already exists
[Employee [emailAddress=anilhk@gmail.com, id=1], Employee [emailAddress=abc@gmail.com, id=2]]
```

employee3 is having the same email address as employee and thus that is excluded from the list.

HTH

Comment: if you find the answer useful please click on the check option on the left of answer

Comment: I personally like this solution, but if Sritam didn't know of sets before, he should know, that insertion order is not preserved in `HashSet`. If preserving insertion order matters, he should use `LinkedHashSet` instead. And `TreeSet` orders its elements by their natural ordering.

Comment: ok updated my code with your request of sending notification when the employee3 object is not added and also updated the output

Comment: Yes sir..I will do that..as per the ans given here employee3 object will be excluded.. but how a user will know that employee3 object is excluded...can we add some check condition here??? yes we can do that by iterating that set object.. but this is not the best possible way r8.. so could you please suggest something??

Comment: i updated my code with the solution of letting the user know that employee3 is excluded. instead of sysout you can write some code to send notification. I am not iterating over the set if u observe. I am just checking if the object exists in the set it should not add. (using set.contains) so i think this solution would work just fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a function which will go through all the nodes of array list and check it your current email address is present before or not . if it present then return false or true and display message.

Comment: Dear laeeq...i did the same thing as you specified here.but it's taking more time..can we use some predefined collection methods or any Java 8 features to achieve this with limited iterations??

Comment: then put your emails in database and just with simple query check if is exist or not

Comment: sqllite is very good database for your work . it is very easy to configer and no installation is required.

Comment: Only store your emails in database just and using search query simple check that is email is already exist or not.   http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/

Comment: This requires O(n^2) time complexity.

Comment: but in database there is no complexity... they use very fast and best  algo.

Answer (score 0):

More efficient way would be to keep a separate set of emails(**Set< String > emailSet**), and check it every time before adding an employee to the list:

```
if (!emailSet.contains(emp.getEmail()) {
    employeeList.add(emp);
    emailSet.add(emp.getEmail());
} else {
    //show error message
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
trigger EmailPreventions on Lead (before insert,before Update){
set<string>LeadSet=new set<string>();
    List<string>LeadList=new List<string>();
    for(Lead objLead:trigger.New)
    {
        if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isInsert)
        {
             LeadList.add(objLead.Email); 
           
        }
        else if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate || trigger.IsUndelete)
        {
            if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isUpdate && objLead.Email!=trigger.oldMap.get(objLead.Id).Email)
            {
               LeadList.add(objLead.Email); 
            }
        }
    }
        Map<string,contact>conMap=new Map<string,contact>();
        for(contact c:[select id,Email from contact where Email IN:LeadList]){
            conMap.put(c.Email,c);
            LeadSet.addAll(conMap.keySet());
              
        }
     for(Lead l:trigger.New){
        if(!conMap.keySet().isEmpty()){
            l.Email.addError('Duplicate Found....!!');
        }        
    }    
  
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).